# Which courses should I take in order to learn ML and AI?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, ai

I want to learn ML and AI so I want to know which courses(It would be nice if the courses were free) should I take in order to do that and in what order should I learn them. I want the courses to provide a deep understanding of the concepts used.

Comment: I hope Google Search is still Alive

Comment: I found many courses but can't decide which one to take up. All of them seem to offer valuable information on the subject so I need some insights.

Comment: No single course can help.. start from Coursera AG, then CS229 and then apply what you have learnt, simple (plus read a lot of blog posts, docs of libs etc)

Comment: Welcome to our community. I recommend watching ML course of Stanford by Pr. Andrew Ng which can be a good initial point. After that, take his deep learning course though you can take them both simultaneously. There are also other ML courses there but take these first. After these you can have a very good perspective where to go :)

Comment: Are both these courses available on coursera?

Comment: Yes, both are on Coursera. First one is free, the second one does have a price but I think there are financial aids available.

Comment: Other than financial aid which is available, you can audit the courses which gives you access to all materials except final exams which are not that much needed unless you need a certificate. If you apply for financial aid, you can also get free certificate.

Comment: I don't see any option to audit the course on deep learning am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, start with:

- Coursera's Andrew Ng's classes

  - [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) (very good for the maths)
  - then go to his [deep learning class](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning) (I haven't done it but I only hear good things from it)
- Udacity had a very good Data Science Specialisation divided in 4 classes. I don't know if it's still available (I did it two years ago) but it is probably either still there or an improved version has replaced it. The 4 courses where:

  - Intro to Data science
  - Visualisation
  - Machine Learning
  - Text Mining

For the rest, I suggest you to do a quick google search...